# Javascript - how to create a timed redirect button and a different button to cancel it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, redirect, onclick

I have the following code. Pressing the first button sends the user to a different URL after 10 seconds.

However, I am also trying to get the second button to cancel that redirect if pressed before those 10 seconds. This doesn't seem to work and the URL redirect still occurs.

I have looked online for various solutions and I am unable to get anything to work. I have also tried swapping out setTimeout/clearTimeout with setInterval/clearInterval and other variations of the code.

I would be willing to have the code changed completely or use Jquery instead etc. I have been trying to do this for past couple of days so any help would be greatly appreciated.

If the redirect countdown could also start again from 10 seconds if the first button is pressed again after pressing the second button, that would be also great.
Javascript

```
<script>
var redirectTime = "10000";
var redirectURL = "https://realmbound.com";
function timedRedirect() {
var timeoutHandle = window.setTimeout("location.href = redirectURL;",redirectTime);
} 
function stopTimer() {
clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
     }  
</script>
```

HTML

```
<button onclick="JavaScript:timedRedirect()">Click me for a timed redirect.</button>

<button onclick="JavaScript:stopTimer()">Stop Timer.</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `timeoutHandle` is in scope function, you must delcare it to global scope it in your order to access it on `stopTimer()`.

```js
let redirectTime = "1000";
let redirectURL = "https://realmbound.com";
let timeoutHandle;
function timedRedirect() {
    timeoutHandle = window.setTimeout("location.href = redirectURL;",redirectTime);
} 
function stopTimer() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="JavaScript:timedRedirect()">Click me for a timed redirect.</button>

<button onclick="JavaScript:stopTimer()">Stop Timer.</button>
```

The rest of the code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct, only thing that you missed is to scope `timeoutHandle` variable as global scope so that `stopTimer` function can access it.

here is the working fixed version of your solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/8uw7f19k/1/

Hope it helps ;-)